# iniciar programa escrito en c al arrancar sistema linux

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, debian, raspberry-pi

Hola esta vez creé un pequeño programa escrito en c que pretendo correr en  una raspberry el mismo ya funciona correctamente, pero ahora me veo en la necesidad de que se ejecute al iniciar el sistema (y funcione sin necesidad de loguearse), la idea seria que al arrancar el aparato funcione directamente el programa sin necesidad de loguearse. Cabe destacar que el mismo lee información por los puertos gpio.

Intente agregando el scrip de la siguiente forma

http://www.stuffaboutcode.com/2012/06/raspberry-pi-run-program-at-start-up.html

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/prototip

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          casero
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Simple script to start a program at boot
# Description:       iniciar  servicio autana system.
### END INIT INFO

# If you want a command to always run, put it here

# Carry out specific functions when asked to by the system
case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "Starting prototip"
    # run application you want to start
    /bin/prototip
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Stopping noip"
    # kill application you want to stop
    killall prototip
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/prototip {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

el mismo cuando lo pruebo de la siguiente forma --sudo /etc/init.d/prototip start ejecuta el programa correctamente, pero cuando apago y enciendo el equipo el programa nunca se inicia. Alguna idea?. Gracias

Comment: de raspberry poco te puedo decir... pero entiendo que la etiqueta [tag:c] aquí pinta poco... da igual que el programa esté hecho en C, C++, Ada, Phyton, ... lo que se pregunta aquí es cómo configurar una raspberry para que ejecute un programa cualquiera al arrancar

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que registrar el script como servicio del sistema:

```
cd /etc/init.d
sudo update-rc.d prototip defaults
```

Otra cosa que te puede dar conflictos en algunos casos es que **el servicio tiene exactamente el mismo nombre que el binario** (el programa en C), que está añadido al PATH del sistema y se puede llamar desde cualquier parte.

Te aconsejo que renombres el script, por ejemplo a "**prototipd**" y vuelvas a añadir el servicio para evitar posibles conflictos.

Además de eso, la ubicación del binario no es la más correcta, deberías ubicarlo en la carpeta de binarios del usuario: `/usr/bin/prototip`

Comment: correcto amigo ya seguí sus recomendaciones pero sigue sin funcionar al inicio, lo extraño es que cuando lo ejecuto después de loguearme funciona perfecto. Se cuando el programa se ejecuta por que se enciende un led indicando que el programa esta funcionando, también probé agregando el comando de arranque a /etc/rc.d/rc.local y en este caso si se apaga el bombillo al iniciar pero noto que no lee por sus puertos ya que cuando lee por el puerto el bombillo parpadea varias veces con una secuencia que le programe.

Comment: Puede que el programa en C se esté ejecutando antes de que esté disponible algo que necesite y falle, por eso cuando te logueas si funciona y antes no. ¿Has mirado en en el log del sistema? Suelen aparecer los errores de este tipo... Mira también que tenga permisos de ejecución para todos los grupos de usuarios.

Comment: también he pensado eso y le coloque un sleep antes de iniciar la aplicacion pero aun sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Ya he resuelto, si alguien algún día le pasa esto deberían probar  de la siguiente forma primero colocar el binario en la carpeta /usr/bin/ y luego editar el archivo /etc/rc.d/rc.local y agregar el scrip, yo lo agregue el comando /usr/bin/prototip y antes de esta linea le coloque sleep 20 para esperar 20 segundos (esto con la intencion de esperar que se ejecuten los demas servicios)y funciona perfecto.

Comment: Perfecto. Seguramente también funcione con esos tips y el tutorial que has seguido, pero indicandole que se ejecute en último lugar (posición 99, en vez de 20 que es la de por defecto).